# How can I set the text direction to RTL in Microsoft Word docx file using powershell?

Tags: powershell, ms-word, docx

I am using powershell to create a docx file.
I was able to create a file and set the style, font and alignment.
My problem is with changing the text direction from default (LTR) to RTL.
This is my working code:

```
$word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$word.Visible = $false
$doc = $word.documents.add()

$selections = $word.Selection
$selections.Font.Name = "Arial"
$selections.Font.Size = 16
$selections.paragraphFormat.Alignment = 2
$selections.TypeText("Hello World!")

$out_path = ".\file.docx"
$doc.SaveAs($out_path)
$doc.Close()
$word.Quit()
```

I did not find any information to set the text direction.
I will appreciate any help,
Thank you.

Comment: i have read that one way to discover such info is to turn on the macro recorder in the app, perform the action, stop the recorder, and then read the recorded commands. apparently they map fairly directly to COM object code.

Comment: You'll have to fiddle with `$doc.Paragraphs.ReadingOrder = 0` See [WdReadingOrder Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdreadingorder?view=word-pia)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your program use this:

```
$doc = $word.documents.add()
$doc.Paragraphs.ReadingOrder = 0
```